# How to display the sibling of a parent element on hover?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a form where the label is only displayed when the input element is on hover.

I've been following the right code on HTML 5 and CSS3 to do that but it's still not working and wondering why ?

Can you show me where my mistakes are ?

On HTML5:

```
<section class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col1">
                <label>What is your full name ?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="username">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First name">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

On CSS3:

```
.col1{
    display: none;
}

.username input:hover .col1{
    display: block; 
}
```

With this code, the element stays hidden when input on hover. How to make it display?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 0):

Put the div with class `col1` inside of the div with the `username` class. This works because when you have a selector `foo bar {...}`, this selects any `bar` that is *inside* of `foo`

```css
.col1{
display: none;
}

.username:hover  .col1{
display: block; 
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
<form>
    <div class="row">
        
        <div class="username">
        <div class="col1">
            <label>What is your full name ?</label>
        </div>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First name">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Last name">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI you had missing tags in your html. In order to be able to make this only with css I would change a little bit the html.

```css
.col1 {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.username:hover > .col1 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="username">
        <label class="col1">What is your full name ?</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First name">
        
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Last name">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's just a matter of structure, yours was a little bit complex so here try this:

```css
label {
display:none;
width:100%;
}
.username:hover label{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="username">
        <label>What is your full name ?</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First name">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Last name">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

your css is basically traversing down from element with class `username`, then finding an input element and when we hover over it, traverse down the children of that input element and find an element with class `col1`.

since input element does not have children, it will now get displayed.

you will first have to traverse up to div element with class `row` then find the element to display. but this cannot be done in CSS.

your best bet is to use jQuery.

see below.

please not that below, when you leave the input element by moving the mouse up it causes it to shift up since it will hide the label element, and will cause flickering.

```js
$('input').on('mouseover',function() {
$('.col1').show();
});
$('input').on('mouseleave',function() {
$('.col1').hide();
});
```

```css
.col1{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col1">
            <label>What is your full name ?</label>
        </div>
        <div class="username">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First name">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Last name">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Great Thank you !

Comment: @elliass If this solved your problem, please click the checkmark to the left of this answer's score to indicate it as the solution for future readers!

Comment: I think your answer is great, but I have a question: why use jQuery when the same thing can be accomplished with the same brevity using normal JavaScript?